# Why am I getting Error 1007: Instantiation attempted on a non contructor, on Android only?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I've seen the error before, usually when we're trying to call a constructor for an object that the interpreter hasn't seen yet. Most likely a dynamic attempt at instantiation. However, I'm currently experiencing the error on a line of execution on Android devices only.

See the guilty function below -

```
public class XMLBuilder
{

    private var elementClasses:Dictionary;
    private var elements:Dictionary;

    public function XMLBuilder() 
    {
        elementClasses = new Dictionary();
        elements = new Dictionary();
    }

    public function buildFromXML(xml:XML):void 
    {
        elements = new Dictionary();

        var element:StardustElement;
        var node:XML;
        for each (node in xml.*.*) {
        //error thrown on line below// 
        element = StardustElement(new elementClasses[node.name()] ());
            if (elements[node.@name] != undefined) {
                throw new DuplicateElementNameError("Duplicate element name: " + node.@name, node.@name, elements[node.@name], element);
            }
            elements[node.@name.toString()] = element;
        }
        for each (node in xml.*.*) {
            element = StardustElement(elements[node.@name.toString()]);
            element.parseXML(node, this);
        }
    }

    public function registerClass(elementClass:Class):void {
        var element:StardustElement = StardustElement(new elementClass());
        if (!element) {
            throw new IllegalOperationError("The class is not a subclass of the StardustElement class.");
        }
        if (elementClasses[element.getXMLTagName()] != undefined) {
            throw new IllegalOperationError("This element class name is already registered: " + element.getXMLTagName());
        }
        elementClasses[element.getXMLTagName()] = elementClass;
    }
}
```

Where the object 'elementClasses' is a dictionary that contains a set of Classes. (And In this case it does, i've checked while debugging on both iOS & Android). And where evaluating 'elementClasses[node.name()] is Class' returns true.

Does anybody know of any quirks in AIR that would cause this to happen on Android only? Or anything in this function that jumps-out?

Comment: Maybe just break it down and store in variables first then put everything together.

Comment: They main idea for a workaround that I have, is a Bootstrap of sorts, in which every possible class that can be instantiated by this function, is instantiated once during the applications startup. To ensure that the interpreter knows about it's constructor before this function is ever executed.

Comment: However, this still doesn't really explain why this is fine on iOS, but throws the error on Android.

Comment: Please post the declaration/definition of `elementClasses`, What is the result of `trace(elementClasses[node.name()])`? What is the result of  `trace(node.name())`?

Comment: updated original code snippet to include constructor and declaration of elementClass Dictionary. Also included the function via which elementClasses is populated. Going to inspect trace(node.name())

Comment: @null: 
trace(elementClasses[node.name()]) : undefined.  
trace(node.name()) : Accelerate (which is one of the classes).

This is strange to me, because if i use IntelliJ's evaluate function during debug, i find that elementClasses[node.name()] returns the class object 'Accelerate'.

Comment: unrelated to the question: the registerClass does a cast which either succeed or fail with error so checking if element exists is irrelevant since it either exist or you got an error prior to that. Maybe you meant to use "as"?

Comment: Actually I do know something that Ios and Android do differently and could be the origin of this problem: system handling of word letter casing. A simple tiny letter case difference can never be a problem in one and cause big headaches in the other.

Comment: @BotMaster: Thank you. Your suggestion set me well on the right track. Wasn't quite the reason but it got me looking in the correct places. Will explain in answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, in AS3 XML node.name() will return a `QName` object. If you look at my `registerClass(elementClass:Class)`, you will see that we're adding classes to the `elementClasses` dictionary using element.getXMLTagName() which returns a String.

Now, apparently in AIR iOS if we attempt a lookup on `someDict[someQName]`, someQName.toString() or some kind of cast is attempted.
Whereas in AIR Android, it would appear that it attempts to use the QName object itself as the key.

I would say that the Android implementation has the expected behaviour, but it's definitely fishy to me...

Fixed code below. `node.name().localName` used instead essentially.

```
public function buildFromXML(xml:XML):void 
{
    elements = new Dictionary();

    var element:StardustElement;
    var node:XML;
    for each (node in xml.*.*) {

    element = StardustElement(new elementClasses[node.name().localName] ());
        if (elements[node.@name] != undefined) {
            throw new DuplicateElementNameError("Duplicate element name: " + node.@name, node.@name, elements[node.@name], element);
        }
        elements[node.@name.toString()] = element;
    }
    for each (node in xml.*.*) {
        element = StardustElement(elements[node.@name.toString()]);
        element.parseXML(node, this);
    }
}

public function registerClass(elementClass:Class):void {
    var element:StardustElement = StardustElement(new elementClass());
    if (!element) {
        throw new IllegalOperationError("The class is not a subclass of the StardustElement class.");
    }
    if (elementClasses[element.getXMLTagName()] != undefined) {
        throw new IllegalOperationError("This element class name is already registered: " + element.getXMLTagName());
    }
    elementClasses[element.getXMLTagName()] = elementClass;
}
```